# How to stop file explorer Windows 8 from showing large icons in folders with videos?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer

Whenever I have a folder with videos, it shows the filenames as large icons. I prefer to show the Details view in all the folders regardless of content type. I don't want to manually change the view every time I create a new folder. I have the same issue when opening a file dialog.

Is there a way to force File Explorer in Windows 8 to always display folder contents in Details view and never have to switch manually? I don't see an option for this under Folder Options.

Comment: It is very sad to find this good question with no answers/comments. Did you find a solution to this?